# How to plot binary data and colour presence by group in R

Tags: r, binary, heatmap

I'm an R beginner and I'm trying to plot simple presence/absence binary data. I have searched everywhere but I can't work out if it's possible to colour the plot by grouping/metadata. So far I have a simple plot with ggplot with the following code:

my data looks like this:

[image: current data]

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("resistance.csv", row.names=1)
data_matrix <- data.matrix(data)
mybinarymap <- heatmap(data_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = c("white","black"))
```

and here's the plot:

[image: binary plot]

However, I'd like to change the tiles to be coloured by the 'Class' that the gene belongs to, such as the extra data would look like this:

[image: data format with metadata]

There would be a tile of white/no colour if the value is 0, and the block would be coloured if the gene is present, with the colour determined by the 'Class' column. Can anyone help or suggest other packages? UpSetR doesn't seem to do what I'm asking for. I'm assuming I'll have to do some reshaping. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all this in `ggplot2`, with a little help from `reshape2` to get your data into long format. Here, I have assumed you have a data frame called `data` that looks like your second data image. I had to put your image through OCR to recreate your data since you didn't make a reproducible example, so it may not be totally accurate:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

ggplot(melt(data), aes(gene, variable, fill = Class, alpha = value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = "gray50") +
  scale_alpha_identity(guide = "none") +
  coord_equal(expand = 0) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(gene = c("aadAl", "aadAS", "aph(3\")-lb", "aph(6)-ld", 
"blaCTX-M-27", "blaOXA-1", "erm(B)", "mdf(A)", "mph(A)", "catAl"
), Class = c("Aminoglycoside", "Aminoglycoside", "Aminoglycoside", 
"Aminoglycoside", "Beta-lactam", "Beta-lactam", "Macrolide", "Macrolide", 
"Macrolide", "Tetracycline"), X598080 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X607387 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), X888048 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), X893916 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -10L))

data
#>           gene          Class X598080 X607387 X888048 X893916
#> 1        aadAl Aminoglycoside       1       1       1       0
#> 2        aadAS Aminoglycoside       0       0       0       1
#> 3   aph(3")-lb Aminoglycoside       1       1       0       0
#> 4    aph(6)-ld Aminoglycoside       1       1       0       0
#> 5  blaCTX-M-27    Beta-lactam       1       1       0       1
#> 6     blaOXA-1    Beta-lactam       0       0       1       0
#> 7       erm(B)      Macrolide       1       0       1       1
#> 8       mdf(A)      Macrolide       1       1       1       1
#> 9       mph(A)      Macrolide       1       0       1       1
#> 10       catAl   Tetracycline       0       0       1       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Melt the data
melted_data <- melt(data, id.vars = c("gene", "Class"))
colnames(melted_data) <- c("gene", "Class", "Sample", "Presence")

# Define a color palette for the classes
class_colors <- c("Aminoglycoside" = "red",
                  "Beta-lactam" = "blue",
                  "Macrolide" = "green",
                  "Tetracycline" = "purple")

# Create the ggplot object for the heatmap
heatmap <- ggplot(melted_data, aes(x = Sample, y = gene, fill = Presence)) +
  geom_tile(color = "gray50") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),  # Rotate x-axis labels
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
 
  coord_flip()

# Create the ggplot object for the annotation bar
# Create the ggplot object for annotation bar without facetting
annotation_bar <- ggplot(melted_data, aes(x = Sample, y = gene, fill = Class)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Aminoglycoside" = "blue", 
                               "Beta-lactam" = "red",
                               "Macrolide" = "green",
                               "Tetracycline" = "orange")) +  # Specify colors for each class
  theme_void()+ # Remove unnecessary elements
  coord_flip()

# Combine both plots using patchwork
library(patchwork)
heatmap_with_annotation <- (annotation_bar / heatmap) + plot_layout(heights = c(0.1, 1))

# Display the combined plot
heatmap_with_annotation
```

[image]